# How do I access Job parameters in a Spring Batch Listener?

Tags: spring-batch

I'm working with `ItemListenerSupport` to do some error handling for ItemReadListener, ItemProcessListener, and ItemWriteListener. I want to access the job parameters in this instance. How do I fetch those? I tried `@BeforeStep` to inject the StepExecution and Jobexecution but neither worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can declare your listener as a step scoped bean and inject job parameters in it, something like:

```
@Bean
@StepScope
public ItemReadListener itemReadListener(final @Value("#{jobParameters['name']}") String name) {
    return new ItemListenerSupport() {
        @Override
        public void afterRead(Object item) {
            System.out.println("in listener, job param name=" + name);
            super.afterRead(item);
        }
    };
}
```

Answer (score 3):

To get the handle of Job Parameters you can implement StepExecutionListener to your listener Class to make use of Overridden methods beforeStep and afterStep

```
@Override
public void beforeStep(StepExecution stepExecution) {
    String name = (String) stepExecution.getJobExecution().getExecutionContext()
            .get("name");

}

@Override
public ExitStatus afterStep(StepExecution stepExecution) {
    if (stepExecution.getStatus() == BatchStatus.COMPLETED) {
        return ExitStatus.COMPLETED;
    }
    return ExitStatus.FAILED;
}
```